# How to bake AO pass from multiple objects into one map?

Tags: python

I want to bake `AO` pass from multiple objects into one map.

But it overlaps the baked map.

[image]

```
import bpy


for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='AO', use_clear=False)
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand. What overlaps what?

Answer (score 0):

Select all objects, and then UV unwrap them. This way objects' UV maps won't overlap. Now you can bake those objects into a single texture.

[image]

Comment: The UV maps are not overlapped.